# How to show all of repository in my account in GitHub?

Tags: github, repository

My friend was shared his repository on GitHub. When I use GitHub Desktop, I could see repository to clone to my local. But I want to see repository in GitHub website, I couldn't see. I click "Repository" section but I couldn't. How can I show all of repository shared with me?

I want to show all of shared repository with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repos shared with you won't show up in **Repositories** until you accept the collaborator invite via email.

Then the repo will be linked to your GitHub account and will live alongside your other repos.